# Adding a column with values chosen from a list based on a date value

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I want to fill a new column with values chosen from a list, based on month number.  Trickier than I expected but I eventually got this to work.  It looks so clunky - is there a neater way?  Sorry if this has been answered before, I have looked...

thanks for any ideas
dave

```
# list of monthly values
ET = [24.20,26.55,40.09,66.41,99.96,128.12,144.25,125.24,95.26,63.59,36.27,27.39]

# extract month number from timestamp date
df4['month_now'] = df4['TIMESTAMP'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m')).astype(int)

#function to choose value for ET
def get_ET(row):
    if row['month_now']==1:
        val=ET[0]
    elif row['month_now']==2:
        val=ET[1]
    elif row['month_now'] == 3:
        val = ET[2]
    elif row['month_now']==4:
        val=ET[3]
    elif row['month_now'] == 5:
        val = ET[4]
    elif row['month_now'] == 6:
        val = ET[5]
    elif row['month_now'] == 7:
        val = ET[6]
    elif row['month_now'] == 8:
        val = ET[7]
    elif row['month_now'] == 9:
        val = ET[8]
    elif row['month_now'] == 10:
        val = ET[9]
    elif row['month_now'] == 11:
        val = ET[10]
    elif row['month_now'] == 12:
        val = ET[11]
    return(val)

# write new column
df4['ET'] =df4.apply(get_ET, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_ET(row) :
   month = row['month_now'] - 1
   val = ET[month]
   return (val)
```

If your code actually work, that should work too ?

You may want to ensure that the entry (row['month_now']) value is between 1 and 12, cuz otherwise it may lead to out of bounds errors

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a function, you can use list comprehension and get what you expect in one line of code:

```
df4['month_now'] = [ET[x-1] for x in df4['month_now']]
```

For each element from 'month_now' you take an element from ET list minus 1. Then you get ET[0] for month = 1, ET[1] for month = 2...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Much faster (over 200x faster than the OP's original code):

```py
import numpy as np

def add_ET(df, ET):
    month_ix = df['TIMESTAMP'].dt.month - 1
    return df.assign(
        month_now=month_ix,  # optional, only if you want that column
        ET=np.array(ET)[month_ix],
    )
```

**Example**

```py
n = 5

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TIMESTAMP': pd.Timestamp('2000') +
    np.random.randint(0, 200, size=n) * pd.Timedelta(days=20),
})
```

Then:

```py
>>> add_ET(df, ET)
   TIMESTAMP  month_now      ET
0 2009-06-02          5  128.12
1 2002-07-29          6  144.25
2 2006-05-29          4   99.96
3 2010-07-07          6  144.25
4 2003-09-02          8   95.26
```

**Speed**

```py
n = 100_000

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TIMESTAMP': pd.Timestamp('2000') +
    np.random.randint(0, 200, size=n) * pd.Timedelta(days=20),
})

a = %timeit -o original_add_ET(df, ET)
# 2.68 s ± 17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

b = %timeit -o add_ET(df, ET)
# 10.9 ms ± 133 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

a.average / b.average
# 245.79
```

**Fun fact: it gets even (a bit) faster if timestamps are ordered**

(The speedup becomes 300x instead of 245x).

```py
df = df.sort_values('TIMESTAMP')

a = %timeit -o slow_add_ET(df, ET)
# (unchanged): 2.67 s ± 10.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

b = %timeit -o add_ET(df, ET)
# 8.9 ms ± 6.65 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

a.average / b.average
# 300.30
```

**Why?**  When the timestamps are sorted, consecutive values of `month_ix` are often equal or differing by just 1. This is very favorable from a [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) point of view.

Comment: Thanks everyone for neat answers!